# GPU overheated, computer won't start?

Tags: hardware-failure, power, gpu

I recently got a new GPU and as I was playing a game today it overheated and my system just went dark.

After about twenty minutes (of leaving my computer off) I open up my case, take out my GPU and exchange it with my older card (which has worked fine always, it just was outdated) . When I went to turn my computer on again, it did nothing. My computer is completely lifeless.

The small light on my motherboard is still glowing green and as far as I can tell all my cables are still properly plugged in and my other GPU is properly connected.

What are some possible reasons for my computer not turning on?
I know it's difficult to troubleshoot an issue like this, but I'm open to ideas and willing to try whatever I can to get my computer running again.

Is it possible that the GPU just killed the rest of my system? I don't see how.

Any advice is welcome, thanks!

Comment: tried connecting to a different slot if possible?

Comment: How did you conclude that the GPU overheated in the first place - is it showing damage of some kind?

Comment: I concluded that the GPU overheated because my room smelled like it was burning down and the fact that my GPU was scorching.

Comment: As to GPU, you "got a new GPU" by changing the whole card out, correct? It should have had a sufficiently large fan to keep it cool under even the most intense graphic loading you could give it. Sure it didn't pull more power than the power supply could produce and smoked a circuit in the power supply?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the whole card. It runs fine for the most part (I had it for a week before I even played any games). So the power isn't the issue. I think the thermal pads on the card came broken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible that the gpu "killed" the rest of my system. If it shorted out, the rush in electricity can burst capacitors or damage the pcie slot.

However, check if the pcie slot is the cause of the issue. Try plugging in your older gpu into a different slot or use integrated graphics (if you have it).

Comment: I only have a single slot. Nothing works. If that's the case, do I need to just buy a new motherboard, or also a processor and other parts? Or is there no good real to know except for testing each part? My motherboard still shows a green light.

Comment: If plugging the old video card into the slot gives you the same symptoms, the motherboard's might be shot. The only other component that might have issues is the power supply. I've had power supplies release their smoke and then the rest of the system doesn't work. Try swapping that out as well.

Comment: Try unplugging the computer and holding down the power button for 60 or so seconds before plugging back in and restarting. This drains out all remaining power to the components and forces BIOS to reinitialize them at POST. In honesty, it's one of the hokiest things I know, but I'll be damned if it hasn't worked for me more times than not. Worth a try.